# how decrease runtime of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, runtime

I have solved the problem but I want to decrease its runtime. So is there any way to do this task?
Task: Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

For example, given nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12], after calling your function, nums should be [1, 3, 12, 0, 0].

My solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        int [] nums1=new int[nums.length];
        int k=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(nums[i]!=0){
                k++;
                nums1[k]=nums[i];
            }}
            for(int i=0;i<nums1.length;i++){
                 nums[i]=nums1[i];

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decrease its runtime"? What is wrong with the current implementation? How did you measure its performance?

Comment: @Tunaki when I submitted this task it was accepted but there was something like that "Your runtime beats 26.14% of java submissions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that a primitive array of `int` will be created to all 0's by default. As such, you just need to create a result array having the same length of the original array and copy into it the non-zero element from the source array:

```
int[] result = new int[array.length];
int k = 0;
for (int v : array) {
    if (v != 0) {
        result[k++] = v;
    }
}
```

I've realized a JMH benchmark of your solution and this one on an array initialized with 100 millions random ints between -10 and 10. The results are (*Windows 10, JDK 1.8.0_66, i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60 GHz*):

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
StreamTest.alternative    avgt   30  208,094 ± 29,928  ms/op
StreamTest.shiftSolution  avgt   30  250,888 ± 26,086  ms/op
```

which shows that this solution is indeed a bit faster (208 ms vs 251 ms).

---

Benchmark code for completeness:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;

@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StreamTest {

    private static final int[] ARRAY = new Random().ints(100000000, -10, 10).toArray();

    @Benchmark
    public int[] shiftSolution() {
        int[] nums1 = new int[ARRAY.length];
        int k = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY.length; i++) {
            if (ARRAY[i] != 0) {
                k++;
                nums1[k] = ARRAY[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums1.length; i++) {
            ARRAY[i] = nums1[i];

        }
        return nums1;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int[] alternative() {
        int[] result = new int[ARRAY.length];
        int k = 0;
        for (int v : ARRAY) {
            if (v != 0) {
                result[k++] = v;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your runtime beats 25.49% of java submissions :( It's increased run time

Comment: @dummy I wouldn't trust this feedback without knowing exactly how they measured it. The benchmark I provided proves that this code is a bit faster.

Comment: @dummy Yes but I mean how technically they measure it. You can make the test for yourself by benchmarking the code.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
public class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        int [] indexes=new int[nums.length];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(nums[i]!=0){
                indexes[k]==i;
                k++;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(i<k)
                nums[i]=nums[indexes[i]];
            else
                nums[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

i have first created a "mask" of all indexes not containing '0'(go over the array once O(N)). then you simply create the new array (go over all the array once O(N)). thus the complexity will be O(N).

Comment: Your runtime beats 25.49% of java submissions.  :(